# "Something went wrong with message: BASE_URL should containts scheme (e.g. http://localhost/)"

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php, localhost, base-url

When I Trying to create a Project on XAMPP Composer Mode and when i trying to Install with the command prompt:
`C:\xampp\htdocs\tokonlen-master>php system/install [baseurl] [db-user]:[db-pass]@[db-host]/[db-name]`
the error then shows up saying that

```
**BASE_URL should containts scheme (e.g. http://localhost/)**
```

I tried to do other commands to fix that error such as:

```
tokonlen-master>php system/install [localhost.com] [db-user]:[db-pass]@[db-host]/[db-name]

php system/install [--base_url=http://localhost/tokonlen-master] [db-user]:[db-pass]@[db-host]/[db-name]

php system/install [baseurl=http://localhost/] [db-user]:[db-pass]@[db-host]/[db-name]

php system/install [base_url=http://localhost/tokonlen-master] [db-user]:[db-pass]@[db-host]/[db-name]

php system/install --base_url=http://localhost/tokonlen-master [db-user]:[db-pass]@[db-host]/[db-name]
```

but the same error message still pops up.

Can you please help me how to solve this error ?

Comment: Please share more details. What does that `system/install` script do? And how is this related to Composer?

Comment: 'system' is the directory of the file while 'install' is the file that must be executed in order to install files to the htdocs folder.